# Battleships Array Bounds Checking

Tags: c#

I am working on battleships and I am using a 2D array and placing the ships (represented) by a number within the grid array like so;

```
/// Places the ships in a sequence on the grid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ship"></param>
public static void PlaceShips(Ship ship)
{     
    Random rnd1 = new Random();
    Random rnd2 = new Random();

        if (ship.Orientation == "h")
        {
            //int r = rnd1.Next(_grid.GetLength(0));
            //int c = rnd2.Next(_grid.GetLength(1));

            int r = 0;
            int c = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < ship.Values.Length; i++)
            {
                _grid[r++, c] = ship.Values[i];
            }
        }
        else if (ship.Orientation == "v")
        {
            //int r = rnd1.Next(_grid.GetLength(0));
            //int c = rnd2.Next(_grid.GetLength(1));

            int r = 3;
            int c = 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < ship.Values.Length; i++)
            {
                _grid[r, c++] = ship.Values[i];
            }
        }
```

I am wanting to use the random methods to set the co-ordinates but my math is off when it comes to checking the array boundaries and keeping the ships within the array. Please could anyone offer any help? Much appreciated. I am thinking I need to mod by the length of the ship and check if the remainder is greater than the ship length but I am struggling to put it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract the length of the ship from the appropriate value when you generate it.

`int c = rnd.Next(_grid.GetLength(1) - ship.Values.Length);` for horizontal, and

`int r = rnd.Next(_grid.GetLength(0) - ship.Values.Length);` for vertical.

You should also only use one instance of Random. By default, Random is seeded with the system clock, so instances created at nearly the same time will get the same seed, and thus produce the same sequence of values. Ideally, you should create a single static instance of random and use it for all random number generation.

Answer (score 1):

When I last programmed a Battleship game this is what I did.

1) Randomly pick a point
2) Determine if it will be placed horizontally or vertically
3) Use for loop to check every section the ship will occupy when placed. For example...

```
invalid_placement = false;
for (int i = 0; i < ship.Values.Length, i++) {
  if (c+i < grid.boundary && _grid[r,c + i] != 0) {
     invalid_placement = true;
  }
}
```

That verifies all spaces the ship will use are open. You must verify that the ship you are placing isn't crossing other ships. It is also important to check whether the spot you are looking at does not fall out of bounds.

Once all checks pass (within bounds && area is clear) you can place the ship across that location. If not, start from step 1.

Quick edit...
I found it easier that when placing ships you always assume ships start on the leftmost position and are placed going right when horizontal and start at the top and placed downward for vertical placements. This simplified logic greatly as you don't need to worry about going below the array bounds.

Answer (score -1):

First off, doing something like this:

`_grid[r, c++]`

is very bad style, since it forces the reader to pause and confirm to themselves whether the ++ is a post-increment or pre-increment. Explicitly do the increment outside of the access.

Secondly, to make sure a ship will remain within the grid, ensure that its start is > 0 and its end (which is start + length - 1) is < grid.length. So for a ship of length L and a grid length G, the start can be anywhere between 0 and G - L.

Comment: Hi, can the downvote be explained? Thanks :D